# How do I display non-US text in Ruby (Unicode)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, iconv

I display text from a database which is encoded as Unicode Vietnam charset. But it doesn't display properly.

[Please see issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKB7d.png).

Comment: Now that i fixed parts of the question I made assumptions about how you are really storing the data in the database. I would also assume that Ruby has a way to set the output encoding.

Comment: Can you specify Ruby version? Do you set Content-Type accordingly?

Comment: I using 1.9.2 for ruby version and 3.0.7 for rails. Content-Type? I don't set this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding this to your database.yml under your environment?

```
encoding: utf8
```